# Use Javascript (jQuery) to display result of request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and currently I am using `ViewData["ResultMessage"]` to show the result of a form (which is done after the user submits & refreshes the page).

I want to do it right after he clicks submit (without refreshing the page). So I have to use Javascript for that, which I am new with. No experience what so ever.

How my form looks like is this:

```
            <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="..">
                <div class="field half first">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Your name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="field half">
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Your email" required />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="Message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="Message" id="Message" rows="5" placeholder="Your message" required minlength="20"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                <p>@ViewData["ContactActionResult"]</p>

            </form>
```

You can see the result is displayed with Razor using `ViewData`. Now I want to do it without refreshing the page and learn JS on the way.

What I have tried so far:

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Receiver",
            data: car,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Congratulations, it worked!");
                $('#contactForm').html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Failed.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I am not sure if I did something wrong or simply not implementing it right. I have the above function inside `<script> here </script>` in my HTML page. Nothing happens when I click the submit button on the form.

Comment: Do you have any script errors in your console ? Open F12 dev tools - >console and check.  Also what is your `Receiver` returning ? How does your `Receiver` signature looks like ?

Comment: First change $("button").click(function (e) to $("input[type=submit]).click(function (e) otherwise your from button is not triggering this finction

Comment: @slon That fixed the issue of the function not working. However, there is another issue now. After it displays the message, the entire website becomes empty (blank). The content is gone.

Comment: It's because you're doing this $('#contactForm').html(data);

Comment: You're replacing the form response html

Comment: @slon You are right, removing that line fixed the issue. May I ask what does that line do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: It removes form by id and adds new html to it by ID

Comment: Check the answer you got, it should work

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an ajax call, It is best if you return a JSON response . You can use the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to determine whether the request is normal form request or ajax call.

You should also consider using to the **PRG** pattern. After successfully saving, you should do a redirect to a GET action where you can render a view, instead of returning to the same view with a viewbag message. If you want to pass some message to the new view/action, use `TempData` instead of `ViewData`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Receiver(string name, string Email)
{       
    // Your existing code to save
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new { status = "success", message = "Created successfully" });
    }
    // Normal form submit. So let's follow PRG pattern
    TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Created successfully";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You can also put a `try/catch` and return a json  like this for error usecase

```
return Json(new { status = "error", message = "some serious error" });
```

In Index action/view, you can read `TempData["ResultMessage"]` and display to user.

Now, for the ajax usecase, in your current view, you can add a div to show the message

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" asp-action="Receiver">

    <div id="msg"></div>

    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Your name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email"  required />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="Message" id="Message" rows="5" 
                  placeholder="Your message" required minlength="20"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />

</form>
```

and now in your ajax call's `success` callback, check the json response coming back from server and show the `message` property as needed. If you are putting the script inside the razor view file, make sure you are putting it inside a `Scripts` section so that it will be evaluated in the proper order (After jQuery is loaded, assuming you load jQuery before calling `RenderSection("scripts")` inside the layout)

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function (){

            $("#contactForm").submit(function (e){

                e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  $(this).attr("action"),
                    data: car,
                    success: function (data){

                        if (data.status === "success")
                        {
                            $('#msg').html(message);
                        }  
                        //to do : handle statuss=="error" as needed                                                 
                    },
                    error: function (data)
                    {
                        alert("Failed.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

For asp.net core, you can write a `IsAjaxRequest` method in your base controller and use that. jQuery will add `X-Requested-With` header with value `XMLHttpRequest` for your ajax calls.

```
protected bool IsAjaxRequest()
{
    return Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
}
```

Comment: There is no `IsAjaxRequest` method in `Request` for me. I am using .NET Core 2 for my project.

Comment: Actually. you can implement it yourself. All it does it checking the header. I will post an update